# query to search the comment by id whether the comment in the document exists or not

Tags: arangodb

The following is the sample json I have. I have comments at both object level and alert level. id here represents random UUID.
It might be simple but I'm new to arangoDB, Thanks in advance.

```
{

id  :   172262546

comments[2]

    0 :     { sourceId  :   172262546
              message   :   ghjjhgfg
              id: 23487698754345678   -> UUID
            }
    1 :     { sourceId  :   172262546
              message   :   ghjjhg
              id: 1426257876879687}
alerts[2]

    0:      { id: 2345678909865234
              name: khguj
              comments[1]:{ sourceId    :   34577654
                            message :   fghjhg
                            id: 098765432345676
                          }
            }
    1:      { id: 349876545678
              name: khguj
              comments[1]:{ sourceId    :   4576544567
                            message :   audwfy
                            id: 567898765434567
                          }
            }

}
```

Comment: not to worry about top most id(172262546) in the object. I just want arango query to search the comment with id exists in the comments array at object level and alert level.

Comment: Your "sample JSON" is not JSON.  Please provide the JSON.

Comment: Also please show the expected output.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (minimal complete verifiable example)